# Reading from followers involving multiple tablets in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

When a read-from-follower enabled query ends up reading from a tablet leader for some parts of the query (because some tablet isn't caught up to desired recency), does the database still read from selected read point `(e.g., now() - <selected_stateless>)` and doesn’t end up reading the latest value from the leader (because that can cause an inconsistent cut on multi-tablet reads, where some parts are served from local tablets, and some from leader zone tablets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

For read-from-follower, there are two settings that set the functionality: `yb_read_from_followers` to enable reading from followers, and `yb_follower_read_staleness_ms` to set the consistency timestamp back in time, to allow a follower to have obtained and apply a change.

If a follower is not able to provide the data consistent with the timestamp minus the `yb_follower_read_staleness_ms` time, the read is redirected to the leader to provide the data.

The re-routing is performed by the tablet_rpc/RpcRetrier. The Request sent to the yb-tserver remains the same. Specifically, it uses the same `read_hybrid_time`. And it also uses the `CONSISTENT_PREFIX` setting even though it may end up going to the leader.